# Reducing code duplication in hibernate sessions

Tags: java, hibernate, design-patterns

I am developing a REST web service using Jersey and Hibernate with Postgres for the backend. I have 3 packages for models, resources and services each. For each method in services I'm duplicating the code:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction transaction = null;
try {
    transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    ***SOME UNIQUE OBJECT***  = (***SOME UNIQUE OBJECT TYPE***) session.save(***SOME UNIQUE OBJECT***);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
} catch (HibernateException e) {
    if (transaction != null) {
        transaction.rollback();
    }
} finally {
    session.close();
}
return ***SOME UNIQUE OBJECT***;
```

Can someone advise how I can do this without duplicating this code. I'm thinking of writing an interface for the entity model classes. Then pass that interface to the above code. Not sure if this is the best way to do this.

Comment: Use DAO design pattern. All persistence methods and database interactions should happen only through your Data access classes. Your service class should call methods on data access classes. Only data access object should invoke persistence methods like session.save()
Create one single method in DAO class, and can refer it multiple times from different service class.
Also make all your service class methods (those are persisting through DAO classes) transactional. Use @transactional on top of method signature.

Comment: @RahulRaj Can you show an example or include a link to some resource? I found this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/data_access_object_pattern.htm.

Comment: Can `Generic Types` solve your problem. Just extract this block as to a `save` method.

Comment: @swdon Thats exactly what you have to do :)
That way, code is not duplicated and more precisely designed for allowing future changes.

Comment: Use `@Repository` annotation for DAO classes, `@Transactional` for all service class methods those are persisting.

Comment: @RahulRaj it'll be very helpful if you can give an example.

Comment: @swdon Alright I will put explanation in answer section.

Comment: I just put some sample code on answer section, check it out..

Comment: Why don't you go with generics approach?

Comment: Use Spring Data, which will autogenerate all of this for you.

Answer (score 1):

In any design patterns, Use of interface is much encouraged and promoted. It will let you add different implementations/features in the future reducing dependency, this is nothing but abstraction.

**An Example:**

```
public interface StudentDao {
   public void save(Student student);
}
```

And we have a implementation class

```
@Repository
public interface StudentDaoImpl implements StudentDao {

   @Autowired  
   SessionFactory sessionFactory; 

   public void save(Student student){
      Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();  
      currentSession.save(student);    
      currentSession.close();
   }
}
```

And service class for example:

```
@Service
public class StudentService {

  @Autowired
  StudentDao studentDao; 

  @Transactional  
  public void save(Student student){
      studentDao.save(student);
  }


}
```

A fully fledged explanation will depend on your project and requirements. However I explained an annotation based simple example for you.

Comment: This is helpful interns of design patter. But it doesn't solve my original issue. Now imagine, I have another entity `Teacher`. Then I will need to repeat this with `TeacherDao`, `TeacherDaoImpl` in which I will end up duplicating a lot of code in `StudentDaoImpl` and `TeacherDaoImpl`...

Comment: Remember, when you follow design patterns, you might end up writing more code (not duplicated code) in this way by creating more classes/methods, but it is the most preferred way of design an application considering the application is subjected to change on future requirements. It is easy to maintain and make changes and easy for any developer to understand the flow. 

You are not adding any duplicated code here, just adding one single method on dao and use it on multiple occurrences at service class by calling them. Can you please elaborate whats duplicate here?

Comment: Firstly, I prefer not to use Spring annotations here. Anyway, your StudentDaoImpl accepts type `Student`. So for another entity `Teacher`, I will need to write a new `TeacherDaoImpl` that needs to open a new session. Without Spring annotations, this will duplicate things like `sessionFactory.openSession()` and `session.beginTransaction();` and the `try` and `catch` in my question.

Comment: So are you using normal JPA to persist or hibernate? the above example is using hibernate annotations, just so you know how powerful and simple hibernate is :) You save multiple lines of code by adding a simple annotation in the signature.

Comment: You could write a class, define a method that returns session object. And finally invoke the method everytime you need session. This could be the case without annotation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [spring-data-jpa](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/) module and create a repository interface that [extends the `CrudRepository interface` for your repository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.definition).

It will have all the standard CRUD methods like `save` on it by default. Most often, you don't have to define an implementation - Spring will provide an implementation for the interface. For very complex repository code you can mix in your own java implementation methods.

It also allows you to define many queries in the interface without writing a single line of code.

Functionality provided by CrudRepository:

```
public interface CrudRepository<T, ID extends Serializable>
    extends Repository<T, ID> {
                                                                                                                       (1)
    <S extends T> S save(S entity);
                                                                                                                       (2)
    T findOne(ID primaryKey);
                                                                                                                       (3)
    Iterable<T> findAll();

    Long count();
                                                                                                                       (4)
    void delete(T entity);
                                                                                                                       (5)
    boolean exists(ID primaryKey);
                                                                                                                       (6)
    // … more functionality omitted.
}
```

Comment: I do not want to use spring in this. Want to go with jersey and hibernate. So, if you can give a custom implementation would be great.

Answer (score 0):

By combining [Rahul Raj's answer on DAO pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45901574/5387794) and various suggestions about Generic Types, I managed to achieve what I wanted as below.

Created entity classes `EntityA`, `EntityB` and `EntityC`. Created an interface called `Object` as below:

```
public interface Object<T> {
    public T addObject(Class<T> entityClass, T newObject);
}
```

and implemented it with

```
public class ObjectImpl<T> implements Object<T> {
    @Override 
    public T getObject(Class<T> entityClass, long objectId) {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = null;
        T entity = null;
        try {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            entity = session.get(entityClass, objectId);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (transaction != null) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return entity;
    }
}
```

Now I can use this `addObject` method to insert objects different entities like

```
public class EntityAService {

    public EntityAService() {
    }
    public EntityA addRedemption(EntityA entityA) {
        Object<EntityA> newEntityA = new ObjectImpl<EntityA>();
        return newEntityA.addObject(EntityA.class, newEntityA);
    }
}
```

`HibernateUtil` provides the singleton `SessionFactory` object. This way I can add any number of different entities and save their instances to database without too much code duplication. If anyone has better suggestions/comments please let me know. Thanks everyone for the ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Using generics, you can do something like this:

```
public static <T>T addObject(Object object, Class<T> type) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    org.hibernate.Transaction tx = null;

    try{
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(object);
        tx.commit();
    }catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    session.close();
    return type.cast(object);
}
```